# Previous row value group by primary key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the columns

```
[QB Revision History],[Pervious QB Revision History]
```

grouping them based on the column

```
Code
```

But I'm not able to do the same. I'm getting these 2 columns

```
[QB Revision History],[Pervious QB Revision History]
```

by using the property

```
ROW_NUMBER()


select ROW_NUMBER()OVER( 
               ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, '01-'+t1.[MonthTitle]) asc) AS rownum,
       t1.[MonthTitle],t1.[Code],t1.[QB Revision History].
into #temp21 
from tbl_SampleQBSizeCDP t1 
group by Code,[MonthTitle],[QB Revision History]
```

I was trying with this query but it didn't give the expected result.

```
select  t1.*,t2.[QB Revision History] as [Pervious QB Revision History] 
#into #temp22 from #temp21 t1, #temp21 t2  
where  t1.Code=t2.Code and t1.rownum>t2.rownum
```

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?
Input:
rownum   MonthTitle    Code                QB Revision History
1        Mar-16      DFSAWGTESTQB51010        New
9        Apr-16      DFSAWGTESTQB51010        R1
11       May-16      DFSAWGTESTQB51010        Revamp

Output:
rownum  MonthTitle  Code    QB Revision History Pervious QB Revision History
9   Apr-16  DFSAWGTESTQB51010   R1  New
11  May-16  DFSAWGTESTQB51010   Revamp  New
11  May-16  DFSAWGTESTQB51010   Revamp  R1

Expected Output:

rownum  MonthTitle  Code    QB Revision History Pervious QB Revision History
9   Apr-16  DFSAWGTESTQB51010   R1  New
11  May-16  DFSAWGTESTQB51010   Revamp  R1

Comment: Can you share with us the structure of your tables along with some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the function that you want is `LAG()`, not `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select t1.[MonthTitle], t1.[Code], t1.[QB Revision History],
       LAG([QB Revision History]) OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, '01-'+t1.[MonthTitle]
                                       ) as prev_revisition_history
 into #temp21
from tbl_SampleQBSizeCDP t1;
```

I am not sure what the `order by` is for.  Your `SELECT` has no aggregation functions.  Without sample data and desired results, it seems unnecessary.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select t1.[MonthTitle], t1.[Code], t1.[QB Revision History],
       t2.QB Revision History]) as prev_revisition_history
into #temp21
from tbl_SampleQBSizeCDP t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from tbl_SampleQBSizeCDP t2
      where CONVERT(DateTime, '01-'+t2.[MonthTitle]) < CONVERT(DateTime, '01-'+t1.[MonthTitle])
      order by CONVERT(DateTime, '01-'+t2.[MonthTitle]) desc
     ) t2
```

Comment: this assumes SQL Server 2012+ from memory.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: LAG function will support only from SQL Server 2012 and above

Comment: @Tanner sorry , I'm using SQL server2008

Comment: Add the relevant tag in future and you will get a more relevant answer, I've added it for you now.